# Form that has values if logged in, and if not logged in it is blank

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<h4>Customer Service - Contact Us</h4>
                        <h5>Send us a message</h5><br>
                        <?php 

                            echo "<p><label>Name</label></p>";
                            echo '<p><input type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="span4" name="name" id="orderID"></p>';
                            echo "<p><label>Email Address</label></p>";
                            echo '<p><input type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="span4" name="email" id="email"></p>';              
                            echo "<p><label>Message:</label></p>";
                            echo '<p><textarea rows="5" name="comment"></textarea></p>';
                            echo '<br><button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>';



                        session_start();
                        $qry = "select * from users where email='$_SESSION[email]'";
                        $result = @mysql_query($qry);

                        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        if($_SESSION['isCustomer'==true){


                            echo "<p><label>Name</label></p>";
                            echo '<p><input type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="span4" name="name" id="orderID" value='.$row['first_name'].'></p>';
                            echo "<p><label>Email Address</label></p>";
                            echo '<p><input type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="span4" name="email" id="email" value='.$row['email'].'></p>';              
                            echo "<p><label>Message:</label></p>";
                            echo '<p><textarea rows="5" name="comment"></textarea></p>';
                            echo '<br><button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>';
                        }}?>
```

hello guys, i have problems with this one, when logged in and has session. it must display the values of the account stored, which is i know how to do. but what i need to know is how to use a condition if there is no one logged in or there is an account logged in.

for example, i am logged in.

when pressing contact us, values are already there.

and when i am not logged in.

contact us will be blank.

how do i do it? Thank you.

here is my checklogin.php. It works i dont know for the isCustomer part but it works.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        //remove this line ******header("location:customer.index.php");
        if($row['type'] == 'admin'){
            $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = true;
            header("location: admin/admin.php");
        } else if($row['type'] == 'customer'){
            $_SESSION['isCustomer'] = true;
            header("location: ../customer.index.php")
;       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always start the session on PHP up top:

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
?>

<h4>Customer Service - Contact Us</h4>
<h5>Send us a message</h5><br>

<?php if(isset($_SESSION['isCustomer'])): ?>
<?php
$qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]' ";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<p><label>Name</label></p>";
    echo '<p><input type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="span4" name="name" id="orderID" value="'.$row['first_name'].'" /></p>';
    echo "<p><label>Email Address</label></p>";
    echo '<p><input type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="span4" name="email" id="email" value="'.$row['email'].'" /></p>';              
}
?>
<?php else: ?>
  <p><label>Name</label></p>
  <p><input type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="span4" name="name" id="orderID"></p>
  <p><label>Email Address</label></p>
  <p><input type="text" style="height: 25px;" class="span4" name="email" id="email"></p>              
<?php endif; ?>

<p><label>Message:</label></p>
<p><textarea rows="5" name="comment"></textarea></p>
<br><button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

Comment: If im logged it it says SESSION HAS ALREADY BEEN STARTED.

Comment: @VinceAgno then you could just remove the `session_start()` on my answer since it has been also initiated

Answer (score 1):

**change this line**

```
 $qry = "select * from users where email='$_SESSION[email]'";
```

**To this**

```
$qry = "select * from users where email='".$_SESSION['email']."'";
```

**and this line to this**

```
if($_SESSION['isCustomer'==true){
```

To this

```
if($_SESSION['isCustomer']==true){
```

**Important Note:** Do not access super global directly into the query, $_SESSION Is superglobal, Use mysqli function or PDO,

Properly escape your data before you use in the query,

Read the comment on your question,

dont use this @, for query, while your are just checking
 Thanks

Comment: When adding       session_start();
it says email is unidentified, but when i remove it, it says session undefined.why is that?

Comment: i mean when session_start it says undefined index, but without it it says undefined variable $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
 if($_SESSION['isCustomer']==true){
   $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
   //echo the fields with the added values
 } else {
   //echo without the values
 }
```

**Method 2:**
use javascript if you have some knowledge with it, by setting IDs for lables and textareas and if you found $_SESSION use document.getElementById to set its value.